# => in C# variable declaration

Tags: c#, variables, lambda

I was reading some C# code and I ran into "=>" in variable declaration and i never saw it before, can anybody explain it

```
    public int Health;
    public bool IsAlive => Health > 0;
```

so what does the second line mean?

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a property, it's short for `public bool IsAlive { get { return Health > 0; } }`.

Comment: It’s a quick way to assign a value to a variable declaration

Comment: @auburg, no, that would be `= Health > 0`, ie. it would be using `=` and not `=>`.

Comment: I am not providing an answer though, as there is almost certainly a duplicate here for this question.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There is no such thing called variable in terms of a class definition. There are properties, fields and methods. ;o)